# Facebook API - How to add a new Admin to a facebook Page using graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-page, facebook-access-token

I am trying to add a new Admin (facebook user) to a facebook Page using Graph API as shown in the screenshot but i get an error message:
"(#200) Either app or user doesn't have permission to modify admins."

When i check the access_token permissions it looks like i have everything in scope and still the request fails. Anyone has encountered this before?
Please check the attached screenshots.

Graph API request

[image]

Page AccessToken permissions

[image]